# How to capture all substrings that match this regex pattern, which is based on a repeat range of 2 or more consecutive times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "((PERS)Marcos) ssdsdsd sdsdsdsd sdsdsd le ((VERB)empujé) hasta ((VERB)dejarle) en ese lugar. A ((PERS)Marcos) le ((VERB)dijeron) y luego le ((VERB)ayudo)"

input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(PERS\)((?:\w\s*)+)\)\s*((?!el)\w+\s+){2,}(le)",
                    lambda m: print(f"{m[2]}"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Here I have used repeat quantifiers, such as `+` (one or more repeats) or `*` (zero or more repeats), in combination with `{}` to specify a range of repeats.

Why this code gives me as output, only the first word and not all the possible words that the pattern `((?!el)\w+\s+){2,}` would cover. Since this pattern captures if there are 2 or more words between `"((PERS) )"` and `"el"` ?

```
"sdsdsd "
```

And not this output, which is what I want to get

```
" ssdsdsd sdsdsdsd sdsdsd "
```

How could I fix my regex to get this result when I print capturing group 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the entire part (`\s*((?!el)\w+\s+){2,}`) into one capturing group.

```py
m = re.search(r"\(\(PERS\)((?:\w\s*)+)\)(\s*((?!el)\w+\s+){2,})(le)",
                    input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(m.group(2))
```